# How to achieve this bottle texture in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The output I have is this

[image]

I need to look like this. Light goldish/yellow in the middle then at the side is slightly dark.

[image]

Comment: it's a glass material, the fact that it is slightly dark on the sides is due to the environment and lights in my opinion. Maybe share your current object so that we can see how you could improve

Comment: Yes. My object material properties are set to Principled BSDF and changing the transmission to 1 and roughness to 0 with a base color #E7C462. I try changing the environment and lights but it is still the same

Comment: Please pack your image if you've used some and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Is this about textures or lighting? You title mentions textures but your question seems to be concerning illumination. Could you rephrase your title to match the content? Also you tag your question blender internal render engine. What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: This is about the texture of the bottle I can't achieve the bottle glass texture. I'm using the blender 3.1

Comment: The blend file is uploading wait a moment Sir moonboots

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/4b752e3f3ade40b587faa3e1a61bdb84 check this file

Comment: The photograph looks like the bottle was photographed on a light table with a lot of light coming from below to blow out the highlights.  It may also have been post processed to remove reflections.  Try lighting from below with a spot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try, I've removed the thickness of your bottle (you have actually 2 bottle objects overlapping and a thickness in one of them, I've also removed this thickness to make things easier), changed the world, pushed a bit its *Background* strength value, created a plane in order to have a white surface around the bottle, created 2 Point lights, and used this material setup, which is a mix between a *Glass* node and a Transparent, with a *Layer Weight (Facing)* node as factor in order to have more transparency at the center of the bottle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir it work!!